# Creating metadata with preprocessor

Tags: c++, metadata, c-preprocessor

For better identification of the resulting file, I want to write some metadata in my compiled (c++) *.exe or *.dll. This metadata should be created during compilation via #define-commands.

Is this possible? Or is there another way to create some easily identifiable data within the file (like metadata)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to windows, if you are using Visual Studio, and you want to be able to add data about a binary you are building, you can add a version resource to your project, which allows you to easily change the version of the resulting binary, as well as add a brief description. You can then view this information in the resulting binary's properties.

I believe any IDE using the ms compiler would also be able to handle a resource file, but I'm not sure how easy it would be to edit them outside of Visual studio.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this, after I am only working (for the next year) with Visual Studio, I am not worried about compatibility problems...   Thank you very much!

Comment: The Version block only has specific fields which you can edit, so depending on how much data (or what type) it might not be appropriate. But sticking data into the resource section is definitely the right approach (whether in the Version block or a custom resource type), as that makes it discoverable without having to grep through the .data section of an exe.

Answer (score 0):

C style strings should be intact after compilation. You could just have something like,

```
char * metadata = "<metadata>Metadata stuff goes here</metadata>";
```

And then just search your .exe file for "metadata" in order to find it.

(although I'm not really sure why you would want to do this...)

Comment: Is there another way to identify a file (without using metadata or stuff like this)?

Comment: Still not quite sure what you're asking, but do you just want to be able to identify the .exe after it's been renamed/moved? If that's the case you may want to look into hashing.

Comment: I want to mark the compiled executable or the DLL, so that another program can identify it and see, if it is still the old one or the new one, independent from the name.